# clone.find attr update with function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some code I'm trying to figure things out as I go...

So I have this :

```
//Increment Color Option Values 
clone.find('#color_option').attr('class', function(i, val) {
  return val + color_option;
});
```

I want to also clear the inline styles on the cloned item, I had a look around and couldn't find anything about mixing attributes + functions, only found how to update multiple attributes using

```
$(selector).attr({attribute:value, attribute:value,...})
```

Which I don't think will work in my case...

As always, any suggestions, explanations fixes will be very welcomed!

UPDATE :

```
// Front Color
            var colorcountFront = 2;
            var color_option = 2;

                $('#addcolorFront').click(function() {
                    var source = $('#clonecolorFront'),
                        clone = source.clone();

                    // Increment input name
                    clone.find(':input.front').attr('name', function(i, val) {
                        return val + colorcountFront;
                    });
                    clone.find(':input[type=radio].front').attr('value', function(i, val) {
                        return val + count;
                    });

                    //Increment garment label
                    clone.find('#colornumberFront').text(function(i, val) {
                        return colorcountFront;
                    });

                    //Increment Color Option Values 
                    //clone.find('#color_option').attr('class', function(i, val) {
                        clone.find('#color_option').attr('style', '');  
                        return val + color_option;
                    });

                    // Put it here
                    clone.insertBefore(this);

                    colorcountFront++;
                    color_option++;
                });
```

That is the code for the cloning that i have, below is the HTML that it clones :

```
<div id="clonecolorFront" class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-5">
        <div class="form-group">
            <span class="input_number" id="colornumberFront">1.</span>
                <input type="text" class="front form-control form-control-short" name="PMS_Front_Color" value="" placeholder="*Type PMS or pick house color from dropdown">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
        <div class="form-group">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg color_option_hide" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Choose Color</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-5">
            <div id="color_option" class="color_option"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I then have some more jquery at the end (below) which takes an attribute (a html color code in this case) and adds that to the output #color_option

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.front-color').change(function() {
        var color = $(this).val();
        $('.color_option').text(color);
        var test_color = $(this).attr('test_color');
        $('.color_option').css('background-color', test_color);
        console.log(test_color);
        console.log(color);
    });
});
```

My list of options (in this case a ul) is as follows :

```
<ul class="modal_color">
        <li style="color:#000;background-color:#ffffff;border:1px solid #333;">
            <label><input type="radio" class="front front-color" name="House_Color_front" value="HOUSE WHITE" test_color="#333">HOUSE WHITE</label>
        </li>
        <li style="color:#fff;background-color:#101820;">
            <label><input type="radio" class="front front-color" name="House_Color_front" value="HOUSE BLACK" test_color="#000">HOUSE BLACK</label>
        </li>
        <li style="color:#fff;background-color:#c8102e;">
            <label><input type="radio" class="front front-color" name="House_Color_front" value="HOUSE RED PMS 186C" test_color="#c8102e">HOUSE RED PMS 186C</label>
        </li>
        <li style="color:#fff;background-color:#ff6c2f;">
            <label><input type="radio" class="front" name="House_Color_front" value="HOUSE ORANGE PMS 021U">HOUSE ORANGE PMS 021U</label>
        </li>
        <li style="color:#fff;background-color:#009639;">
            <label><input type="radio" class="front" name="House_Color_front" value="HOUSE KELLY GREEN PMS 355C">HOUSE KELLY GREEN PMS 355C</label>
        </li>.............................................
```

Hope this helps understand :D

The whole reason for this is, its for a form where users can fill in an order for printing options on clothing.

They have the option to add more than 1 color to each clothing item, i have it on a "click here to add more colors", which is where the clone function comes into it. So they choose first color, this sets the background of #color_options, this is then cloned, but it keeps that original inline style, i want to remove it...

Comment: on the `clone` or the `clone.find('#color_option')` ?

Comment: On the cloned item

Answer (score 0):

If all you're doing is looking to remove inline styles, you should be able to do this by calling the `.removeAttr('style')` method.

```
clone.find('#color_option').removeAttr('style');
```

Comment: When the item is cloned, it incrementally adds a value to the class, e.g class_name then when cloned goes to class_name1 etc etc, but when it gets cloned, it takes the inline style FROM the original source. I want to remove that inline css

Comment: @EdwardHill You're contradicting yourself. _"When the item is cloned, it incrementally adds a value to the class"_.... _" but when it gets cloned, it takes the inline style FROM the original source"_?  Which is it?

Comment: Updated original question with more details, thankyou :)